# "Styles" tab not showing any css rules in chromium developer tools

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In chromium developer tool, while inspecting an element, the css rules associated with the particular element is not showing up in the styles tab. Instead it is showing the box model for the same. I am not sure, What kind of settings will make the style rules visible. Am I missing anything here? Can anyone tell, how to make that style rules visible under styles tab instead of the box model?

FYI: I reinstalled the chrome in my machine. Version number is 43.0.2357.134 m

Screen Shot:

[image]

Comment: Chrome has been doing this a lot for me lately too. I can't see any solid links between sites - it seems to happen randomly. Closing and re-opening the inspector fixes it for me. It's a bit irritating but I would say it's down to Chrome itself. Try filing a bug.

Comment: @thecraighammond Yes man, I restarted the browser and tried opening the developer tool again. It works!! Thanks for sharing your experience. :)

Comment: @thecraighammond It seems that there is some bug basically present with that behaviour.

Comment: I've opened an issue incase you want to track it https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=510774

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with chrome 48.0.2564.97 m (64-bit). Simply closing the developer tool and reopening it solves the problem.

I strongly suggest to report your issues on this topic in order to fix it:
[code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=510774](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=510774)